# Getting elevation from polyline feature using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, elevation

I have imported contour lines from AutoCAD DXF file. I've 3D geometry. Í would like to add a new column to the attribute table of the contour lines. In th field calculator I user the following expression:

```
z(point_n($geometry, 1))
```

[image]
The values in the new fields are -2,147,483,648, but if I click in a field I get NULL.
[image]
If I use the x or y function I get the correct x or y coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

The third dimension was lost when I export the loaded polylines to ESRI shape file. After adding z dimension to the export the formula in field calculator works.

[image]